# MVC3 referencing foreign key during display/edit and ADO.NET Entity Data Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC programming and currently developing an application. I have the following problem which I'm short of ideas how to solve (though I've read some similiar topics here). I want in my View to display another value for my foreign key column (instead of FK value, take a column value from the related table). I'm not sure how to achieve this (through model with the linq statement, create a view model, in the controller, the view?). My knowledge in ASP.NET is really short so I appreciate a more detailed answer how to make it. Thank you in advance ! Check bellow for the case.

I have the following tables in database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MANAGER](
[manager_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[first_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[last_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[team_id] [int] NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_TEAM](
[team_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
```

I use ADO.NET Entitiy Data Model to create class TBL_MANAGER. In the model class I have the following method (maybe it should return IList):

```
public partial class TBL_MANAGER
{
    public static IQueryable<TBL_MANAGER> GetManagersQuery()
    {
        FBMSEntities db = SingletonDB.getDB();
        var queryManager = from manager in db.TBL_MANAGER
                           orderby manager.manager_id
                           select manager;
        return queryManager;
    }
}
```

This is the code from controller (using NuGet PagedList):

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var managers = TBL_MANAGER.GetManagersQuery();
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        var onePageOfProducts = managers.ToPagedList(pageNumber, @FBMS.Common.Constants.MAX_PER_PAGE);
        ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;

        return View(managers);
    }
```

And this is the part in the View where I visualize the data:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.team_id
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.first_name
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.last_name
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.manager_status
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.manager_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.manager_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.manager_id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I want instead of team_id to display the value of TBL_TEAM.name.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you're assigning ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, you can also assign a dictionary of teams to ViewBag.Teams (so that each dictionary item's Key is team_id and Value is name) and then in your view do something like

```
...

<td>
    @ViewBag.Teams[item.team_id]
</td>

....
```

which would look up the name of the team by its ID and render it.